# Какова семантика слова "обуять"?

Tags: лексика, семантика

Искала формы слова **объять** и наткнулась на его  архаичный синоним **обуять**. Примеры  использования вдохновили на вопрос:

**Не изменилось ли значение слова? Всегда ли оно было синонимом** **объять**?

По  Д.Н. Ушакову:

Обуять - (1 и 2 л. ед. и мн. ч. не употр.), обуяет, обуяют, сов., кого-что (книжн. устар.). Охватить, объять (о душевном состоянии). *Кто обуял твой дивный ум? Пушкин. Гордыней обуянный, обманывал я бога и царей. Пушкин (речь Самозванца). Тяжелая дума обуяла Его. Максим Горький.*

Но ведь не обо всех состояниях идёт речь. Не скажешь же: "Меня обуяло счастье, счастливое настроение" или: "Его обуяла радость, обуяло удовольствие, удовлетворение, обуяло желание" и т. п.

Здесь чуть по-другому:

Обуять - (-яю, -яешь, 1 и 2 л. не употр ), -яет; -янный; сов., кого (что) (высок.). О душевном состоянии: охватить, овладеть с неудержимой силой. Обуял страх. Обуян злобой кто-н.(Толковый словарь русского языка. С.И.Ожегов, Н.Ю.Шведова) Откуда взялась добавочка "с неудержимой силой"?

У Державина:

*Коль самолюбья лесть*

*Не обуяла б ум надменный.* (Вельможа)

*Их души славой обуял.* (На переход Альпийских гор) Объять славой - как-то не сочетается...

В письме Ал. Румянцева к Д. И. Титову (1718): *«Великость и новизна сего диковинного казуса весь ум мой обуяла и долго бы я оттого в память не пришел, когда бы Толстой напамятованием об исполнении царского указа меня не возбудил»* (Русск. старина, 1905, август, с. 414).

У А. И. Левитова в рассказе «Сладкое житье»: *«Глафира с капитаном темные ночи, как в песне поется, прогуливала и тайные, забавные речи ему говаривала; потому капитан ее, истинно сказать, как бес обуял»*  - здесь же явно не синоним объять?

В народных заклинаниях, собранных Н. И. Барсовым: ”О раб божий, имярек... Где тут быти, где гуляти, где буяти?“» - а это буяти в каком значении?

А вы какие значения видите в этих глаголах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший ответ на эти вопрос дал В.В. Виноградов. Я процитирую начало, а подробнее можно посмотреть по [этой ссылке](http://wordhist.narod.ru/obujat.html).

> **ОБУЯТЬ**
>
> Слияние омонимов в одно слово, — независимо от резкого различия их
>   первоначальных реальных значений, — можно наблюдать в истории двух
>   созвучных, но морфологически разнородных лексем обуять (обуять —
>   `обезумить, сделать безумным' и обуять —`охватить, овладеть'). В
>   русском литературном языке второй половины XVIII — начала XIX в.
>   создались семантические условия, содействовавшие такому слиянию этих
>   двух омонимов.
>
> В современном русском языке глагол обуять носит явную печать книжного
>   архаизма, хотя он и встречается в языке Горького (например: тяжелая
>   дума обуяла его). Значение этого слова обычно определяется так:
>   `охватить, объять (о душевном состоянии)', например: Его обуяла
>   страсть к деньгам (Ушаков, 3, с. 721—722). Тоска его обуяла... Это
>   определение — не вполне точное. Слово обуять применялось и применяется
>   далеко не ко всякому душевному состоянию. Так, едва ли мыслимы
>   словосочетания: Меня обуяло счастье, счастливое настроение или: Его
>   обуяла радость, обуяло удовольствие, удовлетворение, обуяло желание и
>   т. п.
>
> Кроме того, в словаре Ушакова в качестве иллюстраций к употреблению
>   этого глагола приведены примеры из поэтического языка Пушкина, в
>   которых ясно слышатся отголоски омонима обуять в значении `лишить
>   смысла, обезумить'.

Comment: Как неинтересно стало ... На любой вопрос есть ответ в Интернете, самим уже думать, анализировать не надо...

Comment: @Людмила наличие научных трудов тогда должно было бы сделать значительную часть науки вообще невыносимо бездумной и скучной, так что я не был бы так критичен. Мнение Виноградова — аккуратное, выверенное, приятное к прочтению, но вовсе не единственно возможное. Вот, например, ответ @ Сашка-дурак обнаруживает авторскую точку зрения.

Comment: @Людмила Не всё так просто :) Найти информацию, которая есть в Интернете далеко не всегда удаётся. Например, в этом случае: я сначала посмотрел [словарь XVIII в.](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/) и с удивлением обнаружил там два разных слова "обуять" (сойти с ума и объять), посмотрел несколько толковых словарей (посмотрете в Трубачёве, насколько там всё интересно — obbujati, например, пишется совсем по-другому), а потом уже сузил круг поиска и нашёл в Интернете собранный воедино материал. Ну, может, я зря поспешил на радостях дать ответ — достаточно было оставить ссылку в комментарии.

Comment: @Людмила А во-вторых, мы сами здесь усугубляем ситуацию с упрощением поиска в Интернете :) А за вопрос спасибо — было очень интересно!

Comment: Так ведь и цель была -  чтоб люди сами покопались и увидели, что словцо-то интересное, мне вот так показалось, потом в другом материале столько примеров нашла, вернулась к Пушкину. Может, я половину его стихов неправильно понимала - как объять, а там - обезумить?

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд,  семантика слов объять и обуять,  несколько различна. Объять - осмыслить, воспринять, заключить в объятия ума, образно говоря (сравните - необъятно - недоступно для полного восприятия: необъятная даль, вселенная, необъятные просторы океана). То есть,  это действие индивида.  Обуять же - действие к индивиду.  Его убуевает нечто, овладевает им.  При чём,  не просто овладевает,  а с некой силой, эмоциональной волной - буйностью.  Родственные слова здесь: буйный, буянить. В то время как у объять,  встречаем родственное слово - объятия.

Comment: Так ведь это кто как рассудит. Его объял страх - охватил страх. Обуянный страхом - охваченный страхом. Для кого-то это кажется нормальным, а кто-то говорит: "Нет, обуянный - не просто охваченный, а именно обезумевший от страха". Вот герой Пушкина ,"обуянный силой черной",  обезумел, с памятником стал говорить: «Добро, строитель чудотворный! – Шепнул он, злобно задрожав..."

Comment: Здесь именно слились значения двух устаревших омонимов - обуити и обуяти - овладеть и обезумить.